# Перебор массива объектов в php

Tags: php, массивы, laravel

уже голову поломал, не могу привести к нужному виду.
Есть массив объектов

```
$parameters = [
{name: "immovable_type", value: "apartment"}
{name: "count_room", value: "1"},
{name: "count_room", value: "2"},
{name: "count_room", value: "3"}
{name: "cost_from", value: ""},
{name: "cost_to", value: ""},
{name: "city", value: "637640"}
];
```

мне нужно  получить массив вида:

```
$parameters = [
"immovable_type" => "apartment",
"count_room" => "1,2,3"},
"cost_from" => "",
"cost_to" => "",
"city" => "637640"
];
```

гуру программирование, помогите)

Answer (score 2):

По идее обычного цикла должно быть достаточно и чуть проверок:

```
$parameters = [
    ['name' => "immovable_type", 'value' => "apartment"],
    ['name' => "count_room", 'value' => "1"],
    ['name' => "count_room", 'value' => "2"],
    ['name' => "count_room", 'value' => "3"],
    ['name' => "cost_from", 'value' => ""],
    ['name' => "cost_to", 'value' => ""],
    ['name' => "city", 'value' => "637640"]
];

$result = [];
foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
    if (!isset($result[$parameter['name']])) {
        $result[$parameter['name']] = $parameter['value'];
    } else {
        $result[$parameter['name']] .= ',' . $parameter['value'];
    }
    
}

var_dump($result);
```

Результат:

```
array(5) {
  ["immovable_type"]=>
  string(9) "apartment"
  ["count_room"]=>
  string(5) "1,2,3"
  ["cost_from"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["cost_to"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["city"]=>
  string(6) "637640"
}
```